# Oj Time dump - differences in linux and windows

Tags: ruby, json, windows, ms-access

I have a time stamp I am obtaining from an Access database. Unfortunately, the timestamp represents the time only, but is stored as `1899-12-30 13:05:00 +0000`. The date part of it is in a different field. I need to preserve the data as much as possible while I am storing it in a json blob.

I am using Oj (which is wonderful) to dump the data to json. I have encountered the following behavior on the Windows platform:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'oj'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> t = Time.new(1899,12,30,13,5,0) #this is my actual timestamp
=> 1899-12-30 13:05:00 +0000
irb(main):003:0> Oj.dump(t)
RangeError: bignum too big to convert into `long'
        from (irb):3:in `dump'
        from (irb):3
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):004:0>
```

Now, on linux:

```
2.3.0 :001 > require 'oj'
 => true 
2.3.0 :002 > t = Time.new(1899,12,30,13,5,0)
 => 1899-12-30 13:05:00 +0000 
2.3.0 :003 > Oj.dump(t)
 => "{\"^t\":-2209114500.000000000e0}"
```

I need to make this work on Windows because my source database is MS Access. Please help.

Comment: Can you retrieve the time column from the Access database as a Double instead of a DateTime, e.g., `SELECT CDbl(TimeValue) AS DayFraction FROM tblTimes`, which would return `0.545138888888889` instead of `1899-12-30 13:05:00`?

Comment: That's a good idea, but I have a whole lot of tables, and even more of these fields. I do not want to write a custom `SELECT` for each table. Sequel's `db[:table].all` does great. So far i gave up: brute-testing `Oj.dump` for each `Time` value of each record, and if it fails, I am adding 71 years to the date. Less than elegant, but works, and fast enough.

Comment: Is this a 32/64bit issue ? Min signed long is (-1)*2^31 or -2147483648. Your value is -2209114500, smaller than the smllest possible long.

Comment: Thanks BitAccesser. The Windows machine is a 64-bit machine...

Comment: Maybe a `Ruby` issue, update to latest version. Have you tried `oj.dump(t, options)`? https://github.com/ohler55/oj#options http://www.ohler.com/oj/Oj.html#dump-class_method `time_format` or `mode` maybe help.

Comment: OK, not fixed in latest version (2.3.0) and options also don't provide a fix, but I fund a Workaround. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Time is not handled properly, but you can convert to float. The result string differ a bit from your original:

```ruby
 irb(main):001:0> require 'oj'
 => true
 irb(main):002:0> t = Time.new(1899,12,30,13,5,0)
 => 1899-12-30 13:05:00 +0100
 irb(main):003:0> Oj.dump(t)
 RangeError: bignum too big to convert into `long'
    from (irb):3:in `dump'
    from (irb):3
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
 irb(main):005:0> Oj.dump(t.to_f)
 => "-2209118100.0"
```

Or if you need the exact response you can use an array:

```ruby
irb(main):001:0> require 'oj'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> t = Time.new(1899,12,30,13,5,0)
=> 1899-12-30 13:05:00 +0100
irb(main):012:0> A1 = Array.new(1) 
=> [nil]
irb(main):017:0> A1[0] = '^t'
=> "^t"
irb(main):028:0> A1[1] = t.to_f
=> "-2209118100.0"
irb(main):035:0> Oj.dump(A1).tr("[","{").tr("]","}")
=> "{\"^t\",\"-2209118100.0\"}"
```